# How to use const int with extern

Tags: c++, constants

I run into an interesting issue.
In my file A.cpp
I have a definition

```
const int I = 1;
```

in my file B.cpp
I declare

```
extern const int I;
```

and when I use it, I receive the error message when compiling

```
'undefined reference to I'
```

If I remove `const` in file A, no message and compiles fine. Till now I guessed that `const int` and `int` have different signatures. What is going on here what I do not understand?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `extern` qualifier available when defining a `const` variable. Otherwise it is used like a compile time constant. And only in the file being compiled.